# Find out if password expired or when it expires for user in a specific OU

Tags: active-directory, powershell, users, powershell-v3.0, organizational-unit

Is there any powershell command that outputs the users that have their passwords expired from a specific organizational unit (OU).

If so can it be combined in a script with another command that outputs the time when it expires for all the users in the specific OU ?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get AD Users Password Expiration Report from Specific OU:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=TestOU,DC=TestDomain,DC=Local" -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} -Properties "SamAccountName","msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | 
  Select-Object -Property "SamAccountName", @{Name="Password Expiry Date"; Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}} |
    Format-Table
```

You may also take help from this blog which lets you how to email users a active directory password expiration notification and schedule reports,  alerts and be compliant with all password expiration related tasks to save your time: http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/how-automate-password-change-notification-through-email

Answer (score 2):

Users with expired passwords:

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=MyOU,dc=MyDomain,dc=Local" -filter * -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet | where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"} | where {$_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false} | where {$_.passwordexpired -eq $true}
```

To get time when password expires you should get PasswordLastSet property and add MaxPasswordAge from domain policy (e.g. $DefaultmaxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge).

Please have a look at Password Expiry Email Notification script on TechNet:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Password-Expiry-Email-177c3e27
Good sample for the subject.

Answer (score 2):

To list enabled users with expired passwords in a specific OU:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordExpired -eq $True} -SearchBase "OU=Finance,OU=Users,DC=yourdomain,DC=com"
```

To list enabled users within a specific OU with password expiration dates:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True} -SearchBase "OU=Finance,OU=Users,DC=yourdomain,DC=com" –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"
|
Select-Object -Property "Displayname",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}}
```